# How can I show loader in the center with overlay light grey background in every (button, section, body) case

Tags: css

Grey background should be cover full width and height of parent.

```
<body> 
   <div class="loader"></div> 
</body>
<button> 
    <div class="loader"></div> 
</button>
<section> 
   <div class="loader"></div> 
</section>
```

Comment: What have you tried, where is your CSS?

Comment: Yes! it should cover. Please show what have you tried so far ?

Comment: Whole HTML code should be inside `body` by the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```css
.button-wrap {
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
}

.spinner-wrapper {
  background: lightgrey;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: grid;
  place-items: center;
}

.spinner {
  border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border-top: 5px solid #3498db;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  -webkit-animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
  /* Safari */
  animation: spin 2s linear infinite;
}


/* Safari */

@-webkit-keyframes spin {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}

@keyframes spin {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(360deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<button class="button-wrap">  
  submit
  <div class="inner">
    <div class="loader"></div>
  </div>
</button>

<div class="spinner-wrapper">
  <div class="spinner"></div>
</div>
```